# python-snappy installation error on Windows OS

Tags: python, pycharm, snappy

We are using GCP with Python in our project. For development purpose we are using Windows OS and Pycharm for python code development. We are getting snappy issue error. Post I tried to install `pip install python-snappy` through cmd in venv path.

Receiving below error.

> Failed building wheel for python-snappy.

I tried to download "python_snappy-0.6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl" and install. Still receiving error like Platform not supported.

Comment: Hello what is your python version - can be viewed with  `python -V` or `python3 -V`?

Comment: The `pypi` docs for this project https://pypi.org/project/python-snappy/#description say that it supports MacOS and Posix. That confirms the error message you get on Windows: *platform not supported*.